# Using JavaScript within jelly script

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jelly

I'm trying to use scripts written in JavaScript in Jenkins.
I think that the easiet way would be to call them in .jelly scripts.
For example: I have file

**myCustom.js**:

```
alert("Hello World!");
function myFunction() {
    var x = "", i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        x = x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Next I have: 
**global.jelly** (from tutorial plugin):

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
  <f:section title="Hello World Builder">
    <f:entry title="French" field="useFrench"
      description="Check if we should say hello in French">
      <f:checkbox />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="${resURL}/myCustom.js"> 
      </script>
    </f:entry>
  </f:section>
</j:jelly>
```

The problem is that: there is no effect! Even the Hello World allert does not show...
What am I doing wrong?
If I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

in jelly, it shows allert window, but I cannot call entire document.
Maybe *"${resURL}/myCustom.js"* is not pointing correctly? where should I put my JS file?

One more thing: I've seen other question on Stack, but there is no working anwser, and I can't contact to owner of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question "where should I put my JS file" you can put in src/main/webapp and in jelly file you can write `<script src="${rootURL}/plugin/plugin_name/myCustom.js"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Put your script inside the  tag and create a folder js inside web-app folder.