# Using CSS within jelly script

Tags: javascript, css, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

How to reference css or js file in Jelly for Jenkins plugin.

```
   | java --
   |        |  
   |        jenkins.myplugin --
   |                           |
   |                            SleepBuilder --
   |                                           |
   |                                           SleepBuilder.java
   | resources -- 
   |             |
   |             jenkins.myplugin -- 
   |                                |
   |                                SleepBuilder --
   |                                               |
   |                                                index.jelly
   |                                                style.css
   |                                                scripts.js
```

How to reference style.css and script.js from index.jelly ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="??????\style.css">
```

I tried answers from here [Using JavaScript within jelly script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734159/using-javascript-within-jelly-script) with no luck.